# SQL duplicate values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table with duplicate ID's, but other values in the second column.
Instead of removing all the duplicates with DISTINCT, I need 1 row with the ID and several columns with the values from the second column.

Here is what I mean: (has to become result)

[image: Original]

[image: Result]

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using tag that as well

Comment: Please specify, is column count in resulting table constant (i.e. you know all possible values of your source table second column) or dynamic growing (you don't know all possible values for second column).

Comment: The second column should be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've managed to fix it with this:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT top 1000 *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY
id ORDER BY id) as RN FROM dbo.books) SELECT top
1000 a.id, a.category
, b.category as category2
, c.category as category3
, d.category as category4
from cte a
LEFT join cte b
on a.id = b.id
and a.RN = b.RN -1
LEFT JOIN cte c
ON a.id = c.id
AND a.RN = c.RN -2
LEFT JOIN cte d
ON a.id = d.id
AND a.RN = d.RN -3
WHERE a.RN = 1
```

Comment: The problem I'm still facing is that I have to merge this query with another one.

I've got another query which has a simple SELECT FROM WHERE statement, but with an inner join to this (dbo.books).
I can't manage to make 1 query out of these.